# Android custom password placeholder

Tags: android, android-edittext, placeholder

How to do password field like this? At first line when field is empty. The second when you already enter any symbols.

[image]

Comment: use image view with both checked and unchecked images..  and on button click toggle the visibilty

Comment: which widget you will use to get password input? EditText?

Comment: See this- https://nikshits.wordpress.com/2014/01/22/edittext-with-star-image-for-password/

Comment: Exactly. With EditText field. I did it with custom relativeLayout and child views and EditText but this is not good looking example. Not clear. Any idea?

Comment: Why don't you use some library like [PinEntryView](https://github.com/Philio/PinEntryView) ?

Comment: This d'not look like what i need. Is't work with image for dots placeholder?